# $in inside query, no results in MongoDB, strange behaviour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Sorry for the really bad title, can't figure out how to better describe the issue.

I have this in Schema:
`'language': [String]`

Then in router i send a GET request:

```
let page = Math.max(0, req.query.page - 1);
let take = req.query.take || 50;
let languages = req.query.languages;

let filter = {language: {$in: [languages]}};

let query = Labels.find(filter).limit(100).sort('-_id');

    query.count(function (err, count) {
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        query.skip(page * take).limit(take).exec('find', function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: err
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    count   : count,
                    docs    : docs,
                    language: languages
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This the GET url: 
`http://localhost:3003/api/v1/test/query?take=50&page=1&languages="be","bg"`

The problem is that I always get 0 count, but if i type directly inside the filter var ex. `let filter = {language: {$in: ["be","bg"]}};`  then result is coming back with all the correct documents.

When i console log the `languages` var, I get: `"be","bg"` so the params are fine.

What is going on here?

Comment: `&languages="be"&languages="bg"` "should" parse as an array without needing to post process. Then it would simply be `{ language: { $in: req.query.languages } }` since `req.query.languages` should already be an array, rather than the string you are passing in presently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.query.languages` is not an array. You should change the client side to send a correct array in the query: `http://localhost:3003/api/v1/test/query?take=50&page=1&languages=be&languages=bg` or update an action to parse `languages` parameter.

```
let languages = req.query.languages; // when languages is an array
// OR
let languages = req.query.languages.split(','); // when languages is a string

let filter = {language: { $in: languages }};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change

```
let filter = {language: {$in: [languages]}};
```

to

```
let filter = {language: {$in: languages.split(',')}};
```

and do

http://localhost:3003/api/v1/test/query?take=50&page=1&languages=be,bg